# Why was it patented, even allowed to be so - Patent US7508391

Tags: us7508391, haar, wavelet

The patent states that a cubemap with the lowest resolution of for faces chosen can be used to gather diffuse illumination by doing dot product with the visible faces. Why was that patented, if the patent is in other words the application of Haar wavelet, in which the lowest level is chosen for each side, and with the dot product being the identical operation? There was nothing new, why was that allowed? For reference, Haar wavelet had been discovered years before the patent mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize my discussion below: I believe this patent is even broader and effectively covers ANY rendering technique combining pre-computed light maps with any other form of illumination calculations. It must however be noted that the priority date is in 2004.

Still, links such as the following illustrate that light maps were already common in real-time applications before that time:

http://joshbeam.com/articles/dynamic_lightmaps_in_opengl/

http://www.bigpanda.com/trinity/article1.html

The second link is actually from 1998 (cf. http://www.bigpanda.com/trinity/) and explicitly mentions combining light maps with other advanced forms of lighting (middle of page). To be more specific, see "Each bump map is the light map for the polygon as dynamically lit from a particular range of angles." and "The pixel color is equal to the static light map plus the dynamic bump maps, multiplied by the texture map". The presence of multiple locations / levels with their own light maps is implied by the mention of Quake 3. IMHO this pretty much anticipates claim 1.

Original discussion to follow:

---

Frankly, I believe the patent is even a lot worse than you think. Claim 1 does not even specify anything relating to wavelets. In addition to this, it contains lots of vague and non-standard terminology. "Framing abstraction", "minor/major lights", "n-sides", "ambient value", "value related to", "associating values with" etc.

In fact, aside from "light", "model", and "pixel", there is not a single standard computer graphics term in the entire claim - despite the fact that well-established terminology existed at the priority date for the concepts alluded to in the claim.

---

A computing system for displaying a graphical model comprising:
a processor that employs instructions to perform actions, including:

/* we have some sort of containers, e.g. cube maps or general textures ("n-sides" - whatever that means. 2D? 3D?), for pre-baked lighting */

determining a plurality of framing abstractions in a virtual environment, wherein the framing abstractions having n-sides with n being an integer value greater than two;

/* some lights get baked into the light maps, and some others are not */

for each framing abstraction, determining major and minor lights from a plurality of lights incident to the framing abstraction;

/* baking the effects of some light sources into the light maps */

for each framing abstraction, calculating ambient values, each ambient value being related to an aggregate light illumination at a respective side of the framing abstraction by the minor lights, and associating the ambient values with the framing abstraction;

/* selecting a light map */

selecting a framing abstraction based on a location of the model;

/* combining per-pixel illumination using the "major lights" and the pre-baked values in the light map ("minor lights") */

determining the light illumination caused by the major lights for a pixel of the model; and
modifying the determined light illumination by a value related to one or more of the ambient values associated with the selected framing abstraction; and

/* display on screen */

a display screen arranged to display the model based on the modified light illumination.

---

In summary, no wavelets in the claim. In effect, the claim pretty much covers any rendering technique which combines any sort of pre-baked light maps with any sort of per-pixel lighting. Regardless of what part of the rendering pipeline (if any) is real-time and what part (if any) is an offline pre-process.

Many existing 3D computer graphics systems, from real-time game engines to movie VFX, likely fall under the scope of the claim.